# RecyclerView item removing animation

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

Using default item animator on RecyclerView when removing item it will dissapear first, opening a "hole" behind it, and then items below will slide up to cover this hole.
It's not well looking behavior.

[image]

[image]

1. Green item disappearing, revealling black hole.
2. Red item sliding up only after green is removed completely.

I would like to see sliding items below **synchronously** with removed item disappearing.

But have no Idea how to get this behavior. I suspect the key is in LayoutManager, but can't understand how to deal with it.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this issue ? 
When paginating i always have those "black holes" after removing my loader...

Any help more than welcome

Comment: In short, you must nest content layout (inner) in adapter item layout (outer). layout_height of outer must be wrap_content. Then animate layoutParams.height of inner, and height of item will collapse smooth.